# How can I access the current row/object in an RDLC expression?

Tags: rdlc, microsoft-reporting

I can access the properties of a bound object within an RDLC report by using an expression such as.

```
Fields!MyField.Value
```

How can I access the bound object itself so I can access properties and methods on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't. Hence I decided to not use RDLC reports.

However, DataDynamics [ActiveReports](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ActiveReports/Overview.aspx) provides several ways to bind to data and make the data accessible from code.